# Entity is in a format not supported - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I got table in JSP, which is table's mirror image from database (all records and columns are displayed), and next to it I got button "delete" which deletes row from database by ID. But when I click "delete" button then error appears: `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.` How can I delete row using object?

Here is a code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkout.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkOut(Model model, @RequestParam Patient patient) throws SQLException{

    setAppContext();

    patient = clinicService.deletePatient();

    ModelAndView checkout = new ModelAndView("CheckOut");
    return checkout;

}
```

Line from JSP file which is responsible for delete button:

```
<td><form action="/VirtualClinic/checkout.html?selectedPatient=${patient.id}"  method="post"><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></form></td>
```

DAO:

```
public Patient deletePatient() throws SQLException {
    String query = "delete FROM virtualclinic.patient WHERE idpatient=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

        Patient patient = new Patient();
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, patient.getId());
        int out = ps.executeUpdate();

    return patient;

}
```

Service:

```
public Patient deletePatient() throws SQLException {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    patientDAO = ctx.getBean("patientDAO", PatientDAOImpl.class);

    return patientDAO.deletePatient();

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the entity in the view

Comment: can you please debug and see what are you getting at patient.getId(). I think it is null because you are initializing a new patient and using the id which I assume will always be null

Comment: @user3509208: then another error appears: Required Patient parameter 'patient' is not present

Comment: It means you are not supplying the required parameter(Patient) via your post request because you have @RequestParam Patient patient. you can change it to required to false but you have to somehow send the id of the record that's being deleted to your method after the post. Try something like below  @RequestParam(value = "patient", required = false) Patient patient)

Comment: @user3509208 Ok I did it like you said, and request works, but I guess selected rows dont want to get deleted, it seems like 'patient' is null..

Comment: How are you posting the form? can you get the values that are being sent to your server. I would recommend something like below RequestMapping(value="/checkout.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkOut(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) throws SQLException{

    setAppContext();

    patient = clinicService.deletePatient(id);

    ModelAndView checkout = new ModelAndView("CheckOut");
    return checkout;

}

Comment: change your service to public void  deletePatient(Integer id) throws SQLException . change your DAO to public void deletePatient(integer id) throws SQLException { and use this id to specify the id to query your table. as this is delete why are you returning patient object. it can be void as well

Comment: I changed it like you said and somehow this id is still null, I dont know if the problem lies in dao layer or service, or maybe in controller... I put system.out.println in these methods and put ID as parameter to check, and it displays null..